# How can the OR selector be used with labels in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

How the OR expression can be used with selectors and labels?

```
  selector:
    app: myapp
    tier: frontend
```

The above matches pods where labels `app==myapp` **AND** `tier=frontend`.

But the OR expression can be used?

`app==myapp` **OR** `tier=frontend`?

Comment: According to documentation, it is not possible to OR labels, they are ANDed by default: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/ .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OR isn't supported in your case.

You can try the set-based label selector. Refer to the following link,
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements

Answer (score 33):

Now you can do that :

```
kubectl get pods -l 'environment in (production, qa)'
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#list-and-watch-filtering

Comment: as per the question, requirement is to be able to make OR based selection on different label names

Comment: ^I think this will do precisely that. I just ran it successfully as `kubectl get pods --selector 'label in (value1,value2,value3)'`. Before I would use `kubectl get pods --selector label=value1`.

Comment: @EricHu, you are using the same label name, `label`. The question is about using different label names.

Comment: how do we get this with rest api call?

Answer (score 3):

Allowed keywords are `=, ==, !=, in, notin, exists(only the key identifier)`. 
`==` and `=` are synonyms.
`in` can be used for OR operation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to use `jq`, try something like this:

```
kubectl get nodes --output=json \
  | jq --raw-output '.items[].metadata | select (.labels."node-role.kubernetes.io/master" == "" or .labels."node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane" == "") | .name'
```

Or with `go-template` with no external tools:

```
kubectl get nodes -o go-template='{{range $item := .items}}{{range $taint := $item.spec.taints}}{{if and ( or ( eq $taint.key "node-role.kubernetes.io/master") (eq $taint.key "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane") ) (eq $taint.effect "NoSchedule")}}{{printf "%s\n" $item.metadata.name}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "&&" to combine results as a psudo OR

```
kubectl get pods -l="postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/control-plane" --no-headers -o name **&&** kubectl get pods -l="postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/cluster" --no-headers -o name
```

Here is a method to combine the results and get all columns.

It takes the names of the pods from both results and uses them to get a single result.

```
echo $(kubectl get pods -l="postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/control-plane" --no-headers -o name && kubectl get pods -l="postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/cluster" --no-headers -o name) | xargs kubectl get
```

SAMPLE RESULT

```
NAME                                     READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pgo-66f576957d-lmzls                     1/1     Running     0          10d
pgo-upgrade-84b7c9db8d-wr4jv             1/1     Running     0          10d
postgres-ha-backup-qmxb-zwq9c            0/1     Completed   0          3d23h
postgres-ha-xxx1-5xc4-0                  4/4     Running     0          3d23h
postgres-ha-xxx1-6mpv-0                  4/4     Running     0          3d23h
postgres-ha-xxx1-k9sv-0                  4/4     Running     0          3d23h
postgres-ha-pgbouncer-55cc6bcd98-ftqfj   2/2     Running     0          3d23h
postgres-ha-repo-host-0                  2/2     Running     0          3d23h
```

Comment: Now how can you do that but watch them too.
This fails
echo $(kubectl get pods -l="postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/control-plane" --no-headers -o name && kubectl get pods -l="postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/cluster" --no-headers -o name) | xargs kubectl get -w

Comment: adding "watch" after xargs works