# Querying pods by multiple labels

Tags: kubernetes

I need to retrieve a list of pods by selecting their corresponding labels.
When the pods have a simple label `app=foo`, `k8s-app=bar`, the selection is quite easy:

```sh
kubectl get po -l 'app in (foo), k8s-app in (bar)'
```

The complexity comes with labels that contain special characters, for example: `app.kubernetes.io/name=foo`
So when I query only this label, I don't have a problem, but if I try to add this label to the existing query, it will end by returning `no resources were found`.

```sh
kubectl get po -l app.kubernetes.io/name=foo,app=bar
kubectl get po -l 'app.kubernetes.io/name in (foo), app in (bar)'
```

Any idea how can I join the two labels in a single query?

Comment: the comma separator acts as an AND operator. Are you trying to find pods with labels app.kubernetes.io/name=foo AND app=bar?

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarifying. 
So if I need to get pods that match only one of the labels? What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: Currently this is not possible. You can only OR select a single label (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028731/how-can-the-or-selector-be-used-with-labels-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Thanks @derkoe 
So I guess only using two different queries.

Thanks, if you can post it as an answer, I will close this question

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Currently, Kubernetes does not support OR in label selectors. You can only OR different values of the same label (like `kubectl get pods -l 'app in (foo,bar)'`).

See also [How can the OR selector be used with labels in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028731/how-can-the-or-selector-be-used-with-labels-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 24):

You can use below command for retrieving a list of pods by selecting their corresponding labels.

```
kubectl get pods --selector app=foo,k8s-app=bar
```

Comment: Kudos ! It worked for me! You are saviour :)