# Can you do `or` kubectl label selection instead of `and`?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to do `kubectl get pods -l foo=bar||a=b` instead of `kubectl get pods -l foo=bar -l a=b`, which gives you `and` instead of `or`?

I've played around with set-based requirements, but can't seem to quite get the desired result:

```
$ kubectl get pods -l 'app in (microbot, foo)' -A
NAMESPACE   NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default     microbot-657fc66cc6-f4ll7   1/1     Running   0          18h
```

But, if I try and use multiple headers too

```
$ kubectl get pods -l 'app,k8s-app in (microbot, foobar)' -A
No resources found
```

Comment: Not supported, [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028731/how-can-the-or-selector-be-used-with-labels-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can the OR selector be used with labels in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028731/how-can-the-or-selector-be-used-with-labels-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem this is not supported.

However, you could use the `custom-columns` output format (details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns)) to get there:

```
kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,LABELS:.metadata.labels -A | grep "key1:value1\|key2:value2"
```

You might need to be careful the key:value pairs don't appear in undesired pods in any custom-columns you do choose for this initial output. I.e. if you chose a selector as a column, that might lead to problems with pods that reference the desired pods and might require a bit more sophistication in the query/grep.